# Как сменить кодировку открытого документа в Microsoft Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Открываю файл в UTF-8 и хочу сохранить в Windows-1251. Есть ли такая возможность в Microsoft Visual Studio Code? В самом редакторе или с помощью плагинов?

Comment: посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40365121/3373603)

Comment: Кодировку спрятали в правом нижнем углу, на синей полоске. ОК.

Answer (score 7):

Внизу справа на панели статуса отображается кодировка, в которой открыт файл (например, UTF-8). Жмете на нее. Будет предложено два варианта:

- Reopen with Encoding (открыть заново в другой кодировке)
- Save with Encoding (сохранить в другой кодировке)

Жмете второй вариант, выбираете нужную кодировку из списка.

Answer (score 2):

Вот сюда они спрятали выбор кодировок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]